# This keyword inside a setTimeout function, which is nested under a on() method. And it is not working

Tags: javascript, this

```
$("ul").on("click", ".start", function() {
    console.log("started");
    var timeInput = $(this).parent().children('.time');
    var timeInputValue = timeInput.val();
    var milliSeconds = Number(timeInputValue)*60*1000;
    console.log(milliSeconds);
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("Time Over");
        $(this).parent().children('.task').toggleClass("completed");
    }
        , milliSeconds);
})
```

....................................................................

```
<ul>
        <li><span class="delete">X</span> <span class="start">S</span> <span class="task">Code ToDo</span></li>
        <li><span class="delete">X</span> <span class="start">S</span> <span class="task">Read two books</span></li>
        <li><span class="delete">X</span> <span class="start">S</span> <span class="task">Run</span></li>       
    </ul>
```

I know I am using the `this` keyword wrong inside the setTimeout function, but I want to access,the element with class `.task` respective to the `start`.

How do I do that?

The alert method is working, but the toggleClass is not working.

Comment: this will point to window inside settimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `arrow function` to do that,

```
setTimeout(() => {
   alert("Time Over");
   $(this).parent().children('.task').toggleClass("completed");
 }, milliSeconds);
```

If you are writing your code in ES5 then use the 3rd parameter of `setTimeout`,

```
 setTimeout(function(_this){
   alert("Time Over");
   $(_this).parent().children('.task').toggleClass("completed");
 }, milliSeconds, this);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. Although, the arrow function is a little bit harder for me to understand, but for some reason makes more sense than what I found on the internet.